# Told not to use System.out.println- then what is the alternative?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please tell me what is the alternative to System.out.println

My instructor said to not use this for interviews and when I asked him well then what the hell should I use, he hasn't responded- been 2 weeks( online course)

So please, if I want to print my statement onto the console- what else should I use besides System.out etc.

Thanks everyone for all of your help!

Clearly I am a beginner, can you tell ?!

Comment: I presume he means to use loggers/logging frameworks instead. But I have no problem with using StdOut during interviews, practice, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)

I would argue that `sout` is fine for interviews provided you can explain why a logging framework would be more suitable for production projects.

You can have log levels (e.g. only print to log if running in development environment etc.)

It works better asynchronously than `sout` from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this for a class.  So a more simpler answer is to write out to a text file.  There are many examples out there, here is one:

- http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/write_to_textfile.html